# Autoranging problem for AX5043 transceiver (437.025MHz)

Tags: satellites, transceiver

I am trying to configure AX5043 transceiver(ONSEMI) for PSK modulation and system parameters are as follows:

```
Modulation          :   BPSK
Carrier Frequency   :   437.025MHz

AX5043 chip is interfaced with PIC18F4550 micro controller using SPI.

AX5043 is connected to Crystal Oscillator of 32MHz.

Using internal VCO.
```

Now when I try to do auto ranging for the desired frequency, 437.025 MHz, which is configured in FREQA register(s), I am getting an auto-ranging error, i.e. RNGERR bit is going set after auto ranging is completed.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to ham.SE!  We recommend all users take [the tour](http://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) to get the most from the site.

Comment: @user8883, I believe this question is better suited for http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If yes, how? I am facing the same issue. Also, I would like to say I am studying this IC day and night. Maybe we can help each other. I have developed a full solution to configure and write to this IC in LabVIEW.